# How to split textarea lines into different input fields and edit values

Tags: jquery, html, split, textarea, line

I have this app for mobile devices. It uses txt-files from my server for content and I'm trying to make simple way for anyone to update those files with any web browser.

**My goal is** to split textarea into number of different input fields depending of line number. It's critical to keep completed textarea content order as it were for my app to work.

**Textarea should split in textfields/select option (with unique ID's) as page is loaded. All changes in input fields should show up in textarea on keyUp.**

-

**SOLUTION:** Finally got this working! Thanks for your help **djnose**, your answer was key to make this work.

Working code: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/_bestmanStudio/pq0gaao1/79/) `(http://jsfiddle.net/_bestmanStudio/pq0gaao1/79/)`

I know it looks ugly and I have to write every line seperatly with jQuery, if somenone have better way to do it - I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is that what you wanted to do? 
I forked your idea and changed it a little bit!

it might be a little bit of "fake" with the id, but you will figure out a nice solution :)

```
function createTextFields() {
var text = $("#msg").val();
var textArray = text.split('\n');
for (var singleLine in textArray) {
    var lineValue = textArray[singleLine];
    if (lineValue && lineValue.length > 0) {
        $('#inputs').append(
            $('<input>', {
                type: 'text',
                val: lineValue,
                id: singleLine,
                keyup: function() {
                    var test = $(this).val();      
                    var lines = $('#msg').val().split(/\n/);
                    lines[this.id] = test;
                    $("#msg").html(lines.join("\n"));
                }
            })
        ).append($('<br>'));            
    }            
}    
}

createTextFields();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pq0gaao1/1

Hope it helps

Comment: Hmm that your solution would work perfect if I wouldn't have really need unique ID:s for every form element. (I will use jQuery to force autocorrect for updating ect.) [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pq0gaao1/28/) here you can find small example of form that I need to upkeep these files. Thank you so much for your trouble.

Comment: your solution was great, I instantly upvoted. Seems like I need to be more active here to get my votes public. :/ But really I'm out of options here, **I do need** uniq id:s for those inputs - but I don't have any idea how seperate any lines for their own input field. Can you help me out? God knows Google couldn't. Frustrating to try something like this without any real experience with jQuery or js. :D

Comment: sorry for my late reply ... but that should do the trick.. i updated the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pq0gaao1/80/)